# Changing Kendo UI Multselect tagmode in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I have a kendo ui multiselect control that is declared with the "multiple" tagmode in an MVC view.
I would like to change this tag mode to "single" in javascript under certain conditions.
Does anyone know how to do this?  I am guessing I may have to jump through some hoops to do this!
Many thanks
Russell

Comment: You want to change it server-side or client-side?

Comment: client side, in javascript